# Why PhoneLinetransportDevice throwing error?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, call, hfp

I'm using an API called `PhoneLineTransportDevice` to make an `HFP` and `SCO` connection between my windows and phone so that I can make and pick calls from my pc with a bluetooth connection

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls;
 using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
 
 namespace PhoneLinetransportdevice
 {
 internal class Program
     {
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
         {
 DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(PhoneLineTransportDevice.GetDeviceSelector(PhoneLineTransport.Bluetooth));
 for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
             {
 if (devices[i].Name== "OPPO F11 Pro")
                 {
 Console.WriteLine(i + "#:    " + devices[i].Name);
 var PDevice = PhoneLineTransportDevice.FromId(devices[i].Id);
 var result = await PDevice.RequestAccessAsync();
 if (!PDevice.IsRegistered())
                     {
 PDevice.RegisterApp();
                     }
 var flag = await PDevice.ConnectAsync();
 if (flag)
                     {
 Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                     }
 else
                     {
 Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to PhoneLineDevice");
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

`var result = await PDevice.RequestAccessAsync();` giving denied by the system
I get know that `PhoneLineTransportdevice` automatically make a `HFP` and `SCO` connection instead of creating an `HFP` connection first then `SCO` connection but this is giving error anyone know why?
I have checked this API isnt depricated but still giving error

> Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is
> denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))    at
> Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneLineTransportDevice.RegisterApp()
> at PhoneLinetransportdevice.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in
> C:\StudioApps\PhoneLinetransportdevice\PhoneLinetransportdevice\Program.cs:line
> 25
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at PhoneLinetransportdevice.Program.(String[] args)

Comment: Are you using Windows 11? Is it related to [this issue](https://github.com/BestOwl/MyPhone/issues/26)?

Comment: i am using windows 11 and i dont know if its related to windows or my device @AbuSaadPapa

Comment: If you are using Windows 11 then it is related to the above issue. We need to find out if Microsoft has officially blocked this API from Windows 11 onwards.

Comment: but in windows 10 the RequestAccessAsync results allowed but the app is not getting registered which results in connection failed. Means even after using PDevice.RegisterApp(); the app is still unregistered in windows 10 @AbuSaadPapa

Comment: and in docs its clearly there that this api supports build 22621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft and they said they were not aware of this issue. After checking they said there is some permission issue with this API in Windows 11 and they will resolve it soon. We must wait for Microsoft to resolve this issue.

Comment: when I run the same code in Windows 10  var result = await PDevice.RequestAccessAsync(); gives allowed but I am not able to register my app with PDevice.RegisterApp(); do you have any idea?

Comment: Check this [app](https://github.com/BestOwl/MyPhone). It will be helpful to you. The app works in Windows 10.

Comment: for me its not working in windows 10

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/BestOwl/MyPhone/issues/26#issuecomment-1473975431) he is mentioning it is not working in windows 10. Please check if it is the same version as yours.