Unable to get access permission of PhoneLineTransportDevice on Windows 11 22H2
I am currently developing a hands-free application on Windows using the PhoneLineTransportDevice API. In order to use the related features, I first call PhoneLineTransportDevice.RequestAccessAsync() to request access permissions before proceeding to the next steps. This has been working fine on my development PC running Windows 10.
However, when I run the same code on a PC with Windows 11 22H2, PhoneLineTransportDevice.RequestAccessAsync() always returns "DeniedBySystem". This happens despite the fact that the code and the usage of the API are identical on both systems.
Here is a snippet of my code:
var access = await PhoneLineTransportDevice.RequestAccessAsync();
if (access != DeviceAccessStatus.AlwaysAllowed && access != DeviceAccessStatus.AllowedSubjectToSystemPolicy)
{
    return default(BackgroundTaskRegistration);
}

I expected the RequestAccessAsync() method to return “Allowed” or “AlwaysAllowed” as it does on my Windows 10 system, allowing me to proceed with the next steps of my application. However, it consistently returns “DeniedBySystem” on the Windows 11 22H2 system.
I have been unable to find any documentation or resources explaining why this is happening. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Check Event Viewer on machine to see if there is additional error messages.  You have a credentials issue.  Is Client and Server on the same machine?  Did you install any applications?  When you installed, did you allow all users access to the app or installed for just one user?

Can you elaborate me on the installed apps? I haven't installed any apps particular besides development tools. and this issue occurs before connecting to Server(in this case, the phone)

Read Remarks.  I think you need to register for each user.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonelinetransportdevice.registerapp?view=winrt-22621#remarks  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090850/why-phonelinetransportdevice-throwing-error

You mean PhoneLineTransportDevice.RegisterApp()? As far as I know, RegisterApp() should be called after RequestAccessAsync(), which is also in the question you shared.
Are there any other registration i should do before?

Could you please take a look at Settings-> Privacy & security >Phone calls and check whether the permissions are turned on for your app?

I did give my app permission from Settings. but still it returns DeniedBySystem.
